# Where to get all XML specs for Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I went to this page: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/
and downloaded the files for Glucose Profile and Glucose Service. However, it's really hard to follow.

I then managed to find this [xml](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement.xml) via Google.

This basically shows the number of bits and what they should represent. It's really useful. My question is  where on the bluetooth site is that XML page linked from? I will probably need it for other bluetooth characteristics.

Comment: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/ (full description PDFs).

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I actually downloaded the pdfs as stated in my post but they were actually harder to follow than the XML. I'm actually trying to find a similar page but with just the XMLs linked for the various characteristics.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately I have no idea where to find XML files. I prefer PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML's for the GATT services are links from this page:

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/

Comment: Sorry, but I could not see the link to the xml files from this page. Instead, I used this: https://github.com/oesmith/gatt-xml